# Need help looping through contents of a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox that the user populates with entries. I'm trying to iterate through the listbox and get the SelectedIndex and Value of each entry but I'm getting an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'

My listbox on the form is called listEvents.

Here is what I have:

```
foreach (ListBox item in listEvents.Items)
                {
                    string eventName = item.Text;
                    int index = item.SelectedIndex;
                    //do some stuff with these variables
                }
```

I've tried using ListViewItem instead of Listbox but that doesn't work either (and I have to change item.SelectedIndex to item.Index, and the listEvents listbox control doesn't have a property of Index, only SelectedIndex).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You get that error because you are looking For each `item` with a DataType of `ListBox` inside the `listEvents.Items` which I assume contains strings. Refer to the answer of @Graffito below.

Comment: The `ListBox` has a `SelectedIndex` - the items do not.  do you mean the _index_ of each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = listEvents.SelectedIndex;
foreach (object item in listEvents.Items){
    string eventName = (string)item;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does an object has `SelectedIndex` property?

Comment: It does not. In this example how would I get the index? Or should I just increment an int variable to represent the index (assuming it loops sequentially from 0 forward)?

Comment: @reptiletim & FarzinKanzi: Of course not, I updated my answer.

Comment: i think it will only return the current selected index on the Form when the loop runs. Thus `SelectedIndex` will return improper values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to specify the index of an item, But you can get value of that.

```
foreach (ListItem item in listEvents.Items)
        {
            string eventName = item.Text;
            string value = item.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of each item just use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listEvents.Items.Count; i++)
{
   string value = listEvents.Items[i].ToString();
   // or object value = listEvents.Items[i]; if the listbox is bound to a collection of objects.
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or try this. Messy code but gets the index you need.

```
listEvents.Items.Cast<object>().ToList().ForEach(li => {
    int i = 0;
    string eventName = li.ToString();
    int index = 0;
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Why the cast? And the `ToList`? and the `ForEach`?  This code is unnecessarily messy.